# MVN Install - Erro Java Home

Tags: linux

```
root@vps145918:/opt/Bot# mvn install
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

Informações do Sistema:

```
Debian 8 - 64 Bits
OVH
```

O quê fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente faltou definir a variável de ambiente $JAVA_HOME, siga os passos abaixo:

- Abra o terminal e execute o comando `find /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.x.x-openjdk`
- Em seguida `sudo vi /etc/profile`
- Pressione "i" para entrar no modo de inserção do vi
- Adicione no arquivo as linhas abaixo:

  export JAVA_HOME="Adicione aqui o diretório encontrado pelo comando no passo número 1"

  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
- Pressione "Esc" em seguida `:wq!`
- Execute o comando `source /etc/profile` para aplicar as mudanças no seu shell.
- Tente executar o comando mvn -version para averiguar se tudo funcionou corretamente